# How is foldLeft operator implemented in Scala?

Tags: scala

Why does foldLeft syntax operator works, for example i would expect this code

> (10 /: (1 to 5))(_ + _)

To give me an error "value /: is not a member of Int". How does it expands method /: on all types in type system?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Here is the definition of the "shortcut" operator:

```
def /:[B](z: B)(op: (B, A) => B): B = foldLeft(z)(op)
```

If operator ends with a colon, it is a right-associative. `1 :: Nil` is another example, there is no method `::` on `Int`

this all works:

- `(1 to 5)./:(10)(_ + _)`
- `((1 to 5) foldLeft 10)(_ + _)`  (almost the same as your example,
  but here it's more obvious that foldLeft is actually a method on the
  range object)
- `(1 to 5).foldLeft(10)(_ + _)`

Comment: :: is not a method its an object with apply and unapply methods

Comment: Are you sure? http://www.scala-lang.org/api/current/index.html#scala.collection.immutable.List@::(x:A):List[A]

Comment: we are both right, here is the the `::` case class (=> (un)apply): http://www.scala-lang.org/api/current/index.html#scala.collection.immutable.$colon$colon

Answer (score 0):

Your question is not entirely clear (there's no `n` mentioned in your expression), but:  Operators that end with a colon are interpreted as methods on the right-hand argument, not the left.  Your expression is equivalent to

```
(1 to 5)./:(10)(_ + _)
```

in which `/:` is more clearly seen to be a method of the `Range` object on the left.